# Trying to use CGContextAddArc... nothing is drawn?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to draw an arc. But nothing is drawn?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,340,480);  
    UIView *ui = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:ui];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextAddArc(context, 50, 50, 20, 0, 30, 0); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stroke or fill the arc before its visible. You've got a path on screen but you have to stroke or fill it before draws visibly. Use these to do that..

```
//set the fill or stroke color
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);

//fill or draw the path
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
```

Comment: are you just adding the view and then doing this draw code or is the draw code being done inside -drawRect: ? It looks like you just have a regular UIView, you need to subclass UIView and implement -drawRect inside of it and do your drawing code there and it will render on screen

Comment: thats not where drawing occurs you need to (1) subclass UIView (2) put this drawing code inside -drawRect (3) add your UIView subclass to something on screen and it will call your drawing code in -drawRect here is an example http://goo.gl/1tQDM

Answer (score 2):

When `-viewDidLoad`  is sent, the current graphics context could be anything.  Do your drawing in `-drawRect:`.